# Offset destination data downward from existing data with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from one workbook to another. I can already do this but I am not able to offset the data down some rows. The last part of my code is where my issue is.

```
Sub T1()
Dim sourceTitle As Range, targetTitle As Range

Set sourceTitle = Workbooks("Data to Copy.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Columns("B")
Set targetTitle = Workbooks("Data 
Destination.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")

sourceTitle.Copy Destination:=targetTitle.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Try targetTitle.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row.Offset(2, 0).  Never seen it done quite this way before.  I might use this :)

Comment: Any other suggestions? I get, Run-time error '424': Object required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code, as written, attempts to copy *an entire column* of data into a range of data less than an entire column, which will go beyond the row limitations in Excel.

Rarely is copying an entire column necessary (and if it is, move to a database solution).

Try this:

```
Sub T1()


    Dim wsSource as Worksheet, wsTitle as Worksheet
    Set wsSource = Workbooks("Data to Copy.xlsm").Worksheets(2)
    Set wsTarget = Workbooks("Data Destination.xlsm").Worksheets(1)

    Dim sourceTitle as Range
    Set sourceTitle = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Range("B1"),wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count,2).End(xlUp))

    sourceTitle.Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Offset(2)

End Sub
```